# Cant load ads from AdMop in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ads

**I am trying to put ads in my App using Admop**

**java:**

> package abuhashesh.homam.agecalculator;
>
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
>   import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.view.View;
>   import android.widget.Button;
>   import android.widget.EditText;
>   import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
>   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
>   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
>   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
>   import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
>            import java.util.Calendar;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override                                                                             
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                               
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                           

 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3775451347525525/6444214920");                
    AdView adView =(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);                                 
    AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();                              
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);   
    }

}
```

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id='@+id/adView'
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Errors in Logcat:**

```
08-05 03:55:57.273 15159-15159/? E/Zygote: v2
08-05 03:55:57.274 15159-15159/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
08-05 03:55:57.986 15159-15195/abuhashesh.homam.agecalculator E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/abuhashesh.homam.agecalculator/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/abuhashesh.homam.agecalculator/app_webview/variations_seed_new       (No such file or directory)
08-05 03:55:58.143 15159-15219/abuhashesh.homam.agecalculator E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

**And Thanks For All**

Comment: I have the same problem did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i used to have same error and that because i forgot to add the correct permissions on the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

add those and see if your problem was solved or not